# How do I disable unwanted iPXE boot attempt in Libvirt/qemu-kvm?

Tags: 12.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, pxe

Somehow after upgrading to 12.04, my virtual machines always boot with an attempt to boot from the network first. See this:

[image: virt-manager screenshot]

while I don't have any PXE configuration set:

[image: PXE boot configuration]

I've tried:

- to disable SPICE, by changing the `emulator` to `/usr/bin/kvm` from `/usr/bin/kvm-spice` by editing the XML.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to configure the iPXE, but it doesn't let disable this as a boot option.
- setting another type of NIC - not an option, I need `virtio` for performance reasons. However, `e1000e` doesn't work either.
- removing the NIC: works. However, I need network.
- Googling around. Hard. Lots of result is about failing configured PXE boots.

Not a big issue, but it increases boot times by 50-100% here (booting from SSD), so it's relatively long and annoys me.

How can I disable this and boot from virtual hard disk directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Short answer

Upgrade to libvirt 0.9.10+ (available in Quantal) and add the `<rom bar='off'/>` option to the interface configuration of the machine's XML definition.

#### Long answer

Now that I'm actually using the iPXE boot option I see that the delay occurring in the SeaBIOS screen is not an actual boot attempt. It's just loading the Virtio network option ROM and that takes a few annoying seconds, i.e. **it's not yet doing an iPXE boot attempt**. This lead me to read the libvirt documentation again, and I made an interesting discovery.

As far as I could find, since libvirt 0.9.7 the behaviour has changed to load interface's option ROMs by default. Ubuntu 11.10 shipped with 0.9.2, Ubuntu 12.04 comes with 0.9.8. This definitely makes sense as to why I see this happening since the upgrade to 12.04.

Moreover, this has become configurable in libvirt version 0.9.10 with the `<rom bar='off'/>` option in the XML! (see [here](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsNICSROM)) However, that version of libvirt is not available in Ubuntu 12.04 and I'll have to upgrade to 12.10 or backport it. This makes Ubuntu 12.04 fall between two stools.

Other workarounds are removing the option ROM files as pointed out by @A.H.' and changing the SeaBIOS 'filesystem' as pointed out by @NlightNFotis. However, both ways will basically disable iPXE completely and it's not configurable (if sticking to `virtio` network devices only). As I have a mixed setup of iPXE machines and non-PXE machines, I really need this to be configurable.

Comment: Where is the machine's XML definition?

Comment: @BryceGuinta Create a VM first, then edit its XML definition (advanced) using the command `virsh edit <domain>`

Answer (score 5):

My experiments on the same issue gave me some hints:

The package `kvm-ipxe` installs several PXE option ROMs into `/usr/share/qemu/`:

```
pxe-e1000.rom
pxe-ne2k_isa.rom
pxe-pcnet32.rom
pxe-rtl8139.rom
pxe-virtio.rom
```

Somehow these are automatically found and used by seabios when booting with one of these NICs. When I do a `chmod a= pxe*.rom` on these files and start the virtual machine I get the "error" message

```
kvm: pci_add_option_rom: failed to find romfile "pxe-rtl8139.rom"
```

but it boots cleanly and without PXE.

Comment: Thanks. That gives me a bit of a workaround: using ``virtio`` for general networking devices and ``e1000e`` for VMs that need PXE. However, I still think it's a bug. Somehow Libvirt does not successfully pass the right boot parameters to SeaBIOS.

Comment: What does `chmod a=` do?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get around this in Ubuntu 12.04 by passing the following options to qemu-kvm on the command-line (setting the romfile to blank is the trick):

```
-netdev user,id=hostnet0 -device virtio-net-pci,romfile=,netdev=hostnet0
```

Comment: Cool, but can I specify this in my Libvirt XML machine definition?

Comment: **If you're doing ad-hoc repeated rebooting from the commandline, this is the way to go.** It adds a bit of noise, but instantaneously kills iPXE without requiring you to edit XML files, nuke all of networking, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

From your pictures, I can see that most likely it has to do with the VM BIOS. The VM configuration must not overwrite `SeaBIOS`' settings, something which must be causing the VM to boot from `PXE` first.

*For a first possible solution, try to see if you can enter the Virtual Machine's BIOS and edit the options prevalent there.*

**NOTE:** Will continue to update the answer while my research unveils more possible solutions or causes.

**[EDIT #1]:** You can find information on how to set up the boot order in SeaBIOS [here](http://www.coreboot.org/SeaBIOS#Configuring_boot_order). **That should solve the problem.**

Comment: How can I enter the VM's BIOS? [Wikipedia about SeaBIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeaBIOS) tells me I should try F12 at boot time, but that only triggers skipping the iPXE attempt once.

Comment: @gertvdijk I am currently looking into it. I will get back to you as soon as I find out.

Comment: @gertvdijk This seems somehow related: http://www.seabios.org/pipermail/seabios/2012-March/003526.html

Comment: Thanks, learned new stuff today. However, this seems to apply system-wide and about building a new CBFS (core boot filesystem). As far as I can see, it also disables PXE booting altogether. I don't like this approach and I think it should be possible to prevent iPXE booting attempts runtime as is possible in virt-manager GUI.

Comment: @gertvdijk How do you know it disables it? All I can see is to set up the boot order, *meaning something gets booted prior to something else*.

Comment: Well, I guess it won't be possible to have one VM doing PXE booting and another one having it disabled. Additionally, I am not familiar with building these CBFSs and I assume there must be a better solution (or bugfix).

Comment: @gertvdijk I see. Have it your way mate. =) One last thing: Please consider **upvoting** this answer if it has been any useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent this using "-net none":

```
# qemu-system-i386 -net none
```

Comment: But then you don't have any networking at all! I consider this not really an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that OP still needed networking. In my case running with no network was acceptable.

Comment: This also helped me with my case